# Is there a way to delete messages in SQS with Dataflow once they arrive in PubSub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, amazon-sqs

I have the following infrastructure in place: Dataflow is used to send messages from AWS SQS to Google Cloud's Pub/Sub.
Messages are read with java and Apache Beam (SqsIO).

Is there a way with Dataflow to delete the messages in AWS SQS once they arrive / are read in PubSub and how would that look like? Can this be done in java with Apache Beam?

Thank you for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's no in-built support for message deletion, but you can add code to delete messages that are read from AWS SQS using a Beam [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo). But you must perform such a deletion with care.

A Beam runner performs reading using one or more workers. A given work item could fail at any time and a runner usually re-runs a failed work item. Additionally, most runners fuse multiple steps. For example, if you have a `Read` transform followed by a delete `ParDo`, a runner may fuse these transforms an execute them together. Now if a work item fails after partially deleting data, a re-run of such a work item may fail or may produce incorrect data.

The usual solution is to add a fusion break between the two steps. You can achieve this with Beam's [Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.java#L65) transform (or just by adding any transform that uses [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey)). For example, the flow of your program can be as follows.

```
pipeline
    .apply(SqsIO.read())
    .apply(Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DeleteSQSDoFn()))
    .apply(BigQuery.Write(...))
```

Comment: could you give a link where 'DeleteSQSDoFn' is documented?